# Wilcards in filename path calling batch scripts

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm attempting to write a batch script to call several other batch scripts. All these other scripts have titles beginning with a number 01, 02, 03, etc., but the rest of the name is a program and version. Since these versions constantly change, I was trying to just call on 01*.bat, rather than the full filename so that I shouldn't have to edit this master script.

My question is can wildcards not be used in calling other batch scripts, or starting programs, if so how?

Alternatively is there a better way to go about doing this?

I have little code up to now but I've tried the following

```
Start test*.bat
Call test*.bat
echo for /f "tokens=*" %%A IN ('dir /b test*.bat') Start %%A
```

and neither work.

Answer (score 2):

You were near. In your last command

- The `echo` just shows the command, it does not execute it
- There is no need to use a `for /f` to process the output of a `dir` command, a simple `for` will be enough
- You forget the `do` clause of the `for` command
- Unless you want to execute all the batch files in parallel, instead of a `start` command you need a `call` command.

```dos
for %%a in (test*.bat) do call "%%a"
```

For each file in the indicated set call the selected file

Comment: This seems to be closer, but it still does not seem to like any batch after the first. I just keep getting a 

    "%filename% is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

It does seem to run all simultaneously though, is there not a way to run through one at a time waiting until the previous has completed?
Each batch is a standalone batch with "Start /Wait %somefile%".

Comment: @zcr07, previous code runs one batch file after the previous one has ended. As there is not any `%filename%` in the posted code, the problem is not here, but in the called batch files.

Comment: It's just a bunch of different install files being pointed too. For example, one is simply `START /WAIT %cd%\Src\dotNetFx_4_5_0_Setup.exe` 
and then the next should run `START /WAIT %cd%\Src\dotNetFx_4_5_2_Setup.exe`
It runs the first one just fine, but fails on any subsequent scripts. Even if I `::comment out the main script within the first batch file`
it will continue to run the second but fail on the third.

Comment: @zcr07, maybe the problem are not the batch files Have you tried to check the exit status of the previous step?. More [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms994349.aspx#dotnetfxref_topic3)

Comment: I'm not sure how to check the exit status other than checking the active processes, but as an example, one of the batch files simply open up the System Properties as a quick step for it to be put onto a domain. When I run that batch it starts with the first install and also immediately brings up System Properties, even though each script includes a `Start /Wait` line.